# Is it possible to specify a custom color scheme for a single vim session?

Tags: vim, color-scheme, iterm

I have a default colour scheme on Vim which loads every time I open Vim. I would like to load a different colour scheme in some cases, by doing something like

> vim -custom

when launching vim from iTerm. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a command to vim via option `--cmd <command>` or `-c <command>` or `+<command>`:

```
$ vim --help
...
+<lnum>             Start at line <lnum>
--cmd <command>     Execute <command> before loading any vimrc file
-c <command>        Execute <command> after loading the first file
...
```

---

These commands will set `colorscheme` to `darkblue`:

```
vim -c 'color darkblue'
vim --cmd 'color darkblue'
vim +'color darkblue'
```

Comment: As the colorscheme is usually set in `.vimrc`, the `--cmd` one will be overridden by that. (But the others do work.)